# Tensorflow not finding files

Tags: tensorflow

So as I try to run my code it keeps saying that it can't find an image but it in fact is there. I've tried a lot of things but nothing works. Can someone please help me? This is code is trying to read images from the nist dataset and then i am trying to train a model. Here's my code and error code:

```
import os
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf

upper_level_dirs = open("/Users/cam/reader/top_level_dirs")
upper_level_dirs = upper_level_dirs.read().split()

print(upper_level_dirs)

file_names = []
labels = []

for folder in upper_level_dirs:
    for filename in os.listdir("./train/" + folder + "/"):
        file_names.append("./train/" + folder + "/" + filename)
        labels.append(folder)


# Use a custom OpenCV function to read the image, instead of the standard
# TensorFlow `tf.read_file()` operation.
def _read_py_function(file_name, label):
  image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
  image_decoded = tf.image.decode_image(image_string, channels=3)
  image_resized = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image_decoded, 28, 28)
  return image_resized, label
  # image_decoded = cv2.imread(file_name.decode(), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
  # return image_decoded, label




dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((file_names, labels))

dataset = dataset.map(_read_py_function)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

dataset = dataset.batch(32)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

for _ in range(100):
  sess.run(iterator.initializer)
  while True:
    try:
      sess.run(next_element)
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
      break
```

Errors:

```
2018-03-27 12:59:58.001455: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2018-03-27 13:00:01.574038: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1278] OP_REQUIRES failed at whole_file_read_ops.cc:114 : Not found: train_7a_02017.png; No such file or directory
2018-03-27 13:00:01.576585: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1278] OP_REQUIRES failed at whole_file_read_ops.cc:114 : Not found: train_7a_02017.png; No such file or directory
2018-03-27 13:00:01.578373: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1278] OP_REQUIRES failed at whole_file_read_ops.cc:114 : Not found: train_7a_02017.png; No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1330, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1315, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1423, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 516, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: train_7a_02017.png; No such file or directory
     [[Node: ReadFile = ReadFile[](ReadFile/filename)]]
     [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?,28,28,?], [?]], output_types=[DT_UINT8, DT_STRING], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Iterator)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "split2.py", line 46, in <module>
    sess.run(next_element)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 908, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1143, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1324, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1343, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: train_7a_02017.png; No such file or directory
     [[Node: ReadFile = ReadFile[](ReadFile/filename)]]
     [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?,28,28,?], [?]], output_types=[DT_UINT8, DT_STRING], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Iterator)]]
```

Comment: It is fairly certain that the file is in fact not there. Double check the filename including the path, make sure it matches exactly where the file is located. There is likely no other solution.

Comment: Can you put an absolute path instead of a relative path?

Answer (score 0):

I also find that error and my solution is:
  Maybe you create the path by windows and the path end with 'CR' when you view the txt with notepad++, which cant read by linux.
 You can replace 'CR' with '' by notepad++. Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and using tf.as_str_any() solved the problem for me.
This because the file is an object and not a string, so you have to decode it (generally UTF-8) to a string.

So your code would look like this:

```
def _read_py_function(file_name, label):
  image_string = tf.as_str_any(file_name)
  image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
  image_decoded = tf.image.decode_image(image_string, channels=3)
  image_resized = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image_decoded, 28, 28)
  return image_resized, label
```